# Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyObject' to return type 'NSComparisonResult'

Tags: swift, sorting, nsarray, nsdate, comparator

I have a Swift based iOS application. I am trying to use one of the Swift sort methods to sort my array of objects by the "createdAt" `NSDate` property.

My array has a bunch of `PFObject` - these objects have different properties including an `NSDate` property called "createdAt".

All I want to do, is to order the array so that the objects which are the oldest, are sent to the bottom of the array.

Here is my code:

```
let sortedArray = (self.statusData.copy() as! NSArray).sortedArrayUsingComparator { (obj1, obj2) -> NSComparisonResult in

  if (((obj1 as! PFObject).createdAt?.compare((obj2 as! PFObject).createdAt!)) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) {
      return obj2
  }

  else {
      return obj1
  }
}
```

However when I try to return the objects, I get the following error:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyObject' to return type
>   'NSComparisonResult'

I don't understand whats wrong, why can't I just return the date comparison result which is determined my if statement?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: you didn't return `NSComparisonResult`, you were returning the `obj2` and `obj1`

Comment: @Breek But I need the method ```compare``` in order to compare the two ```NSDate``` values. I can't just do ```return obj2 > obj1```

Comment: thislooksfun has your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that it's expecting a return type of `NSComparasonResult` and you're returning an`AnyObject`. However, you are already getting an `NSComparasonResult` in your existing code. Therefore, simply replace all of that with this:

```
let sortedArray = (self.statusData.copy() as! NSArray).sortedArrayUsingComparator { (obj1, obj2) -> NSComparisonResult in
    return (obj1 as! PFObject).createdAt?.compare((obj2 as! PFObject).createdAt!)
}
```